# py2app prescripts

Tags: python, monkeypatching, py2app

The [py2app documentation](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) mentions prescripts, being run by `__boot__.py` prior to the main python script. I couldn't find a way to easily specify any prescript on the setup.py file or build process.

I did however manage to 'hack' `__boot__.py` manually and add another `_run(prescript)` command before my main `_run(main_script)` and it seemed to work fine. It would however be much better using the standard py2app build process.

What I'm essentially trying to do is monkey-patch my sites-packages.zip file prior to the main script being launched. The prescript essentially checks for updates on the server, and if there are any, downloads them, and then overwrites the site-packages.zip file. Much quicker than having to re-install the application from scratch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the docs](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#developing-recipes): your `py2app.recipes` package must contain a recipe whose `check` method returns a `dict` including the `'prescripts'` key whose value is, and I quote,

> A list of additional Python scripts to
>   run before initializing the main
>   script. This is often used to
>   monkey-patch included modules so that
>   they work in a frozen environment. The
>   prescripts may be module names, file
>   names, or file-like objects containing
>   Python code (e.g. StringIO). Note that
>   if a file-like object is used, it will
>   not currently be scanned for
>   additional dependencies.

See [the built-in recipes sources](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/py2app/recipes/) for examples.  This package (as installed on your machine) is where you'll need to add your own custom recipes.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this already, but couldn't work out which kind of recipes I should add where. Ended up using a completely different solution that doesn't involve any of those after all...